# How to import from csv file with elixir/phoenix?

Tags: csv, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a CSV file to process in Elixir and populate some data in my repo. I followed [How to import users from csv file with elixir/phoenix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43891367/how-to-import-users-from-csv-file-with-elixir-phoenix) but my need is slightly different;

I am trying to use the headers: true method from CSV module, but can't figure out how to use it or inspect the content of its answer (Elixir isn't yet as clear to me as ruby ;)

Any suggestion?

The file is processed (I get the flash message)

```
def import(conn, %{"item" => item_params}) do
    item_params["file"].path
    |> File.stream!()
    |> CSV.decode(separator: ?;, headers: true) #headers: [:level, :DIM0, :DIM1, :DIM2, :DIM3, :DIM4]
    |> Enum.map(fn (item) ->
      Item.changeset(%Item{}, %{level: Enum.at(item, 0), dim0: Enum.at(item, 1), dim1: Enum.at(item, 2), dim2: Enum.at(item, 3), dim3: Enum.at(item, 4), dim4: Enum.at(item, 5)})
      #|> (fn(item) -> Logger.info "Csv content : #{inspect item}" end).()
      |> Repo.insert
    end)
    |> Enum.filter(fn
      {:error, _} -> true
      _ -> false
    end)
    |> case do
      [] ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "Imported without error")
        |> redirect(to: item_path(conn, :index))
      errors ->
        #errors = parse_errors(errors)  # create this fun
        conn
        |> put_flash(:error, errors)
        |> render("import.html")
    end
end
```

Comment: Try accessing the item's columns by name. Change `Enum.at(item, 0)` to `item["level"]`, `Enum.at(item, 1)` to `item["DIM0"]`, etc since you're using `headers: true`.

Comment: I tried but without success ; 

I also tried IO.inspect() and get a #Stream<[enum: #Function<59.111446431/2 in Stream.transform/3>,
 funs: [#Function<47.111446431/1 in Stream.map/2>]]> 

do you have any idea on how to print out the content of the enum ?

Comment: Where did you add the `IO.inspect`? Try adding this inside the `Enum.map` function: `IO.inspect(item)`.

Comment: Found it ! t was due to Microsoft excel  :-( Lost 2 days... txs for your help ! For those who look for a solution, find a nice .csv template online to work with.

Comment: I noticed that a working file doesn't work anymore after passing through MS hands...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anybody's needs, this is my code :

```
item_params["file"].path
  |> File.stream!()
  |> CSV.decode(separator: ?;, headers: [:level, :dim0, :dim1, :dim2, :dim3, :dim4])
  |> Enum.map(fn (item) ->
    {:ok, fields} = item
    Item.changeset(%Item{}, %{topic_id: item_params["topic_id"], level: fields.level, dim0: fields.dim0, dim1: fields.dim1, dim2: fields.dim2, dim3: fields.dim3, dim4: fields.dim4})
    |> Repo.insert
  end)
```